# Python skipping negative values

Tags: python, skip

So I have the following code to find a min number of 3 given values where `abc,xyz,mnl` are list containing values to compare as:

```
for q , (a,b,c) in enumerate(zip(abc,xyz,mnl)):
    print (a,b,c)
    if int(a) < int(b) & int(a) < int(c):
        print "a","\t",a
    elif int(b) < int(a) & int(b) < int(c):
        print "b","\t",b
    elif int(c) < int(a) & int(c) < int(b):
        print "c","\t",c
```

And I'm getting this output

```
('3137775', '-7589493', '-1419231')
('6199235', '-3810275', '-8726482')
('2649229', '-4119818', '3726604')
b    -4119818
('-1960710', '2758796', '9426184')
a   -1960710
```

The problem is it prints the min value which is 'b' on 2 iteration and skips 3 iteration before that printing. And it keeps on doing that  at each iteration which contains more than one value in negative(-ve) as `'-7589493', '-1419231'` we can see in first iteration.

Why it can't print the min value for each iteration

Comment: you mean `and` and not `&`; `&` is not the logical `and` - it's the bit-wise operation.

Comment: Oh so the issue  was wrong operator

Comment: @Anjan yes, although the method chosen isn't brilliant. It's quite complex to follow for a start

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`&` it's binary `AND`, not logical `AND`.

Try this:

```
for q, (a, b, c) in enumerate(zip(abc, xyz, mnl)):
    print(a, b, c)
    if int(c) > int(a) < int(b):
        print("a", "\t", a)
    elif int(c) > int(b) < int(a):
        print("b", "\t", b)
    elif int(b) > int(c) < int(a):
        print("c", "\t", c)
```

or using `AND` logical operator:

```
for q, (a, b, c) in enumerate(zip(abc, xyz, mnl)):
    print(a, b, c)
    if int(a) < int(b) and int(a) < int(c):
        print("a", "\t", a)
    elif int(b) < int(a) and int(b) < int(c):
        print("b", "\t", b)
    elif int(c) < int(a) and int(c) < int(b):
        print("c", "\t", c)
```

Answer (score 2):

a slightly different approach:

```
abc = ('1', '2', '3')
xyz = ('3', '1', '2')
mnl = ('2', '3', '1')

for q , (a,b,c) in enumerate(zip(abc,xyz,mnl)):
    (aa, bb, cc) = (int(a), int(b), int(c))
    print(aa, bb, cc)
    m = min(aa, bb, cc)
    index = (aa, bb, cc).index(m)
    print 'abc'[index], m

# output:
(1, 3, 2)
a 1
(2, 1, 3)
b 1
(3, 2, 1)
c 1
```

i left the `q` and `enumerate` from your example even though it is not used.

Comment: From the original poster's code, it seems the values are strings, not ints

Answer (score 2):

[As hiro says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32540938/2808510), you can use the `min` function. But, if you would rather, this should work:

```
abc = (1,2,3)
xyz = (2,3,1)
mnl = (3,1,2)

for q , (a,b,c) in enumerate(zip(abc,xyz,mnl)):
    print (a,b,c)
    a,b,c=int(a),int(b),int(c)
    if b > a < c:
        print ("a",a)
    elif a > b < c:
        print ("b",b)
    elif b > c < a:
        print ("c",c)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3)
a 1
(2, 3, 1)
c 1
(3, 1, 2)
b 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
for q, tup in enumerate(zip(abc, xyz, mnl)):
    combo = ((int(x), y) for x, y in zip(tup, 'abc'))
    # example of combo: ((5, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (8, 'c'))
    print '{1}\t{0}'.format(*min(combo))
```

The key here is the calculation of combo. In this approach, `tup` is a tuple of 3 strings such as `('5', '2', '8')`. `combo` is a combination of this tuple after converted to `int` and zipped with the labels `['a', 'b', 'c']`